# Vertical Slick carousal not showing last slider completely in responsive devices

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with vertical slick slider in responsive. I am not able to see last slider completely, it showing half slider on some devices,  like iphone5,6,7.. etc.

```
jQuery('.slick-carousel').slick({
                        vertical: true,

                        verticalSwiping: true,
                        slidesToShow: 2,
                        slidesToScroll: 1,
                        infinite: false,
                        customDots: false,
                        centerMode: false,
                        dots: false,
                        centerPadding: '0px',
                        responsive: [{
                            breakpoint: 481,
                            settings: {
                                customDots: true
                            }
                        }]
                    });
```

I want to show complete slider on scroll in responsive.

Comment: please help me for this. i need solution as early as possible.. thanks!

Comment: Anyone knows above issue, why last slider not showing completely..